# Product folder which share eclipse-repository and eclipse-plugin with tycho

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, tycho

I simplify the project structure i have to ask these question, my root folder is structured like this :

- my.project.parent

  - pom.xml
- my.project.product

  - pom.xml
  - pom-product.xml

The pom.xml in `my.project.parent` is my root pom i first compile using `mvn clean install`

After that, i open `my.project.product`, linked by relative path to `my.project.parent/pom.xml`

My problem is that i need, using tycho, that `my.project.product` packaging type need to be an `eclipse-plugin`, and also an `eclipse-repository` at the same time.

Actually i compile the my.project.product using `mvn install -f pom-product` which run the two pom in one time.

Is it possible to do the same thing using only one `pom.xml` in tycho ?

**-- Update --**

You can find the software project here : github.com/gama-platform/gama . The `msi.gama.application` contain the double `pom.xml`. One is for generating a product with `eclipse-repository` (executable of the software), and the other generate the plugin using `eclipse-plugin` (needed as dependance for developper of extension of the software)

This is why msi.gama.application is a plugin **and** a repository (generating the executable of software)

Comment: im not sure what you are trying to do, but why my.project.product packaging type need to be an eclipse-plugin, and also an eclipse-repository at the same time?

Comment: The product project can also be a plugin for developper of extensions. It represent the core of the software.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Tycho, but based on [documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Packaging_Types), `eclipse-plugin` packaging generates one plugin, while `eclipse-repository` packaging generates update site which could include multiple plugins of possibly various versions.

It is quite normal concept in Maven to have a "distribution" project that bundles multiple artifacts into one distribution bundle. This seems to be quite similar to `eclipse-repository` packaging, even if in your case it's just one project being bundled.
This means that you need the following projects:

1. Product project with `eclipse-plugin` packaging
2. Distribution project with `eclipse-repository` packaging and dependency on the first one (since it basically bundles the first one).
3. (Optional) Aggregator project that includes the previous two as modules, to build both in one go easily. You can also specify this aggregator project as parent to the first two and put common configuration in it, if necessary.

The actual structure doesn't matter much to Maven itself, but can matter to the IDE you use. The most intuitive one is to put aggregator/parent pom.xml in the root folder, and put each of the other projects in their own separate sub-folders.

Comment: Note that if you plan on bundling more than just this plugin in your update package (eclipse-repository), then you should decouple this update package generation from plugin generation. You can have different completely separate maven projects generating plugins, then another completely separate project bundling all of them together (letting Maven retrieve them from Maven repository using the dependency mechanism).

Comment: You can find the software project here : https://github.com/gama-platform/gama The msi.gama.application contain the double pom.xml. One is for generating a product with `eclipse-repository` (executable of the software), and the other generate the plugin using `eclipse-plugin` (needed as dependance for developper of extension of the software) This is why msi.gama.application is a plugin and a repository (generating the executable of software)

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with Tycho, so I cannot be more precise than this. Can you try splitting msi.gama.application sub-module into two: the plugin sub-module that includes everything plugin needs, and the repository sub-module that includes everything else. Then make repository sub-module specify maven dependency on the plugin sub-module. Based on Tycho documentation on [eclipse-repository packaging](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/eclipse-repository) the repository should pick up a plugin that is included like that.